# Что делать при этой проблеме?

Tags: python

```
def listen():
    while True:
        data = stream.read(4000, exception_on_overflow=False)
        if (rec.AcceptWaveform(data)) and (len(data) > 0):
            answer = json.loads(rec.Result())
            if answer['text']:
                yield answer['text']



def search():

   

        webbrowser.open_new_tab('https://www.google.com/search?q='+str(listen))
        
        webbrowser.open_new_tab('https://www.google.com/search?q=' +str(listen)) 


print(listen)
```

Браузер выдает:
<function listen at 0x0000025C49968CA0>

Comment: наерное, `+str(listen())`

Comment: извиняюсь +str(listen()) ошибка: <generator object listen at 0x00000256BA293DF0>

Comment: и что вы хотите получить?

Comment: Если listen это функция-генератор, то логично предположить, что, вероятно, стоит бы её запихнуть в какой-нибудь цикл

Comment: Данная функция должна делать запрос в гугл

Answer (score 0):

упрощенный пример, что пытаетесь сделать вы:

```
def listen():
    for i in range(2):
        yield i

def search():
    print(listen())
    print(listen())

search()

# <generator object listen at 0x000001B4741BDD90>
# <generator object listen at 0x000001B4741BDD90>
```

использовать next

```
def search():
    aa = listen()
    print(next(aa))
    print(next(aa))
    #print(next(aa))

search()

# 0
# 1
# исключение StopIteration
```

использовать цикл

```
def search():
    for x in listen():
        print(x)

search()
# 0
# 1
```

Информация предоставлена гугл поиском